# Почему модальное окно не срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // Modal

    const modalTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal]'),
        modal = document.querySelector('.modal'),
        modalCloseBtn = document.querySelector('[data-close]');

    modalTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.classList.add('show');
        modal.classList.remove('hide');
    });

    modalCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.classList.add('hide');
        modal.classList.remove('show');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.btn {
  width: 220px;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s all;
  outline: 0
}

.btn_white {
  background-color: #fff
}

.btn_dark {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #fff;
  border: none
}

.btn_min {
  height: 50px
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.divider {
  width: 330px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.title {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0 100px
}

.header__left-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 550px
}

.header__logo {
  max-width: 170px
}

.header__logo img {
  width: 100%
}

.header__links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.header__link {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 45px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #303030
}

.header__link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 110%;
  left: -5%;
  bottom: -1px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 8px;
  background: #54ed39
}

.header__link:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

.sidepanel {
  position: fixed;
  left: 60px;
  top: 240px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}

.sidepanel__text {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 14px
}

.sidepanel__text span {
  display: flex;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50px)
}

.sidepanel__divider {
  width: 1px;
  height: 165px;
  background-color: #000
}

.sidepanel__icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px
}

.sidepanel__icon img {
  width: 100%
}

.preview {
  padding: 28px 0 100px 0;
  position: relative
}

.preview__life {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 35px
}

.bgc_blue {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -155px;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 900px;
  background: rgba(146, 242, 255, .15);
  z-index: -1
}

.tabcontainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 1130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)
}

.tabcontent {
  width: 850px;
  position: relative
}

.tabcontent img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}

.tabcontent__descr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: -177px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 359px;
  background: rgba(251, 254, 93, .8);
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}

.tabheader {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 35px 30px;
  background-color: #fff
}

.tabheader h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px
}

.tabheader__items {
  margin-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 26px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000
}

.tabheader__item {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s all
}

.tabheader__item_active {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700
}

.offer {
  padding: 70px 0 100px 0;
  position: relative
}

.offer .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.offer .bgc_y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1109px;
  height: 780px;
  background: rgba(243, 255, 222, .45);
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50px
}

.offer__text {
  width: 580px
}

.offer__descr {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 24px
}

.offer__action {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end
}

.offer__advantages {
  width: 330px;
  margin-top: 50px
}

.offer__advantages h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.offer__advantages h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 70px
}

.offer__advantages-text {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 21px
}

.offer__slider {
  width: 650px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end
}

.offer__slider-counter {
  display: flex;
  width: 180px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.offer__slider-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)
}

.offer__slider-prev {
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.offer__slider-next {
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.offer__slider #current {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000
}

.offer__slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px
}

.offer__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}

.calculating {
  padding: 50px 0
}

.calculating .title {
  text-align: center
}

.calculating__field {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: rgba(146, 242, 255, .15);
  padding: 30px 0 40px 0
}

.calculating__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 30px
}

.calculating__subtitle:first-child {
  margin-top: 0
}

.calculating #gender:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url(../icons/switch.svg) center center/cover no-repeat
}

.calculating__choose {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-content: center
}

.calculating__choose-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  transition: .3s all
}

.calculating__choose-item_active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #54ed39
}

.calculating__choose_medium {
  width: 743px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto
}

.calculating__choose_big {
  width: 930px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto
}

.calculating__choose_big .calculating__choose-item {
  width: 200px
}

.calculating__divider {
  width: 490px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}

.calculating__total {
  width: 490px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}

.calculating__result {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700
}

.calculating__result span {
  font-size: 42px
}

.menu {
  padding: 40px 0 50px 0
}

.menu .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start
}

.menu .title {
  text-align: center
}

.menu__field {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(249, 254, 126, .25)
}

.menu__item {
  width: 320px;
  min-height: 450px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300
}

.menu__item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover
}

.menu__item-subtitle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.menu__item-descr {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px
}

.menu__item-divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  margin-top: 40px
}

.menu__item-price {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px
}

.menu__item-price span {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700
}

.order {
  padding-bottom: 80px
}

.order .title {
  text-align: center
}

.order__form {
  margin-top: 70px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}

.order__form img {
  transform: scale(1.5)
}

.order__input {
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  outline: 0
}

.promotion {
  padding: 70px 0 240px 0;
  position: relative
}

.promotion .container {
  display: flex
}

.promotion .bgc_y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 499px;
  background: rgba(243, 255, 222, .35);
  z-index: -1;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0
}

.promotion__text {
  width: 50%
}

.promotion__descr {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 300
}

.promotion__descr span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px
}

.promotion__timer {
  width: 50%
}

.promotion__timer .title {
  text-align: right
}

.promotion__timer .timer {
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 95px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}

.promotion__timer .timer__block {
  width: 102px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center
}

.promotion__timer .timer__block span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: 700
}

.footer {
  min-height: 180px;
  background-color: #303030;
  padding: 45px 0 50px 0;
  color: #fff
}

.footer .container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end
}

.footer .subtitle {
  font-size: 20px
}

.footer .link {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff
}

.footer .call {
  text-align: right
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.modal__dialog {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto
}

.modal__content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 14px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer
}

.modal__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.modal__input {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  outline: 0
}

.modal .btn {
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
.show {
  display: block
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Food</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__left-block">
            <div class="header__logo">
                <img src="icons/logo.svg" alt="Логотип">
            </div>
            <nav class="header__links">
                <a href="#" class="header__link">Доставка питания</a>
                <a href="#" class="header__link">Второй пункт</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="header__right-block">
            <button class="btn btn_white" data-modal>Связаться с нами</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="sidepanel">
        <div class="sidepanel__text"><span>Социальные сети</span></div>
        <div class="sidepanel__divider"></div>
        <a href="#" class="sidepanel__icon">
            <img src="icons/instagram.svg" alt="instagram">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="sidepanel__icon">
            <img src="icons/facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="preview">
        <div class="bgc_blue"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tabcontainer">
                <div class="tabcontent">
                    <img src="img/tabs/vegy.jpg" alt="vegy">
                    <div class="tabcontent__descr">
                        Меню "Фитнес" - это новый подход к приготовлению блюд: больше свежих овощей и фруктов. Для
                        людей, которые интересуются спортом; активных и здоровых. Это абсолютно новый продукт с
                        оптимальной ценой и высоким качеством!
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                </div>
                <div class="tabheader">
                    <h3>Выберите стиль питания</h3>
                    <div class="tabheader__items">
                        <div class="tabheader__item tabheader__item_active">Фитнес</div>
                        <div class="tabheader__item">Премиум</div>
                        <div class="tabheader__item">Постное</div>
                        <div class="tabheader__item">Сбалансированное</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="preview__life">Живи полной жизнью!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>

    <div class="offer">
        <div class="bgc_y"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="offer__text">
                <h2 class="title">Что мы можем вам предложить?</h2>
                <div class="offer__descr">
                    Наша основная идея - это правильное питание. Оно может быть простым и вкусным. Мы не просто
                    доставка, мы сервис! Мы взяли на себя все расчеты БЖУ, калорийности, объемов порций и прочие важные,
                    но скучные аспекты. Вам остается только полезная, сытная и правильная еда, которую мы привозим прямо
                    под дверь.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="offer__action">
                <button class="btn btn_dark" data-modal>Связаться с нами</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="offer__advantages">
                <h2>Быстро и полезно</h2>
                <div class="offer__advantages-text">
                    Готовка дома занимает много сил, времени и нервов. Мы привозим еду сразу на целый день, и ты можешь
                    действовать так, как тебе удобно, не подстраиваясь ни под кого и будучи уверенным в качестве
                    продукта!
                </div>
                <h2>Правильный рацион</h2>
                <div class="offer__advantages-text">
                    Мы разработали специальное меню, где учтены все нюансы правильного питания, от баланса БЖУ до их
                    приготовления и дробления рациона.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="offer__slider">
                <div class="offer__slider-counter">
                    <div class="offer__slider-prev">
                        <img src="icons/left.svg" alt="prev">
                    </div>
                    <span id="current">03</span>
                    /
                    <span id="total">04</span>
                    <div class="offer__slider-next">
                        <img src="icons/right.svg" alt="next">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="offer__slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="offer__slide">
                        <img src="img/slider/pepper.jpg" alt="pepper">
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="offer__slide">
                        <img src="img/slider/food-12.jpg" alt="food">
                    </div>
                    <div class="offer__slide">
                        <img src="img/slider/olive-oil.jpg" alt="oil">
                    </div>
                    <div class="offer__slide">
                        <img src="img/slider/paprika.jpg" alt="paprika">
                    </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>

    <div class="calculating">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="title">Рассчитаем вашу потребность в калориях?
            </h2>
            <div class="calculating__field">
                <div class="calculating__subtitle">
                    Ваш пол
                </div>
                <div class="calculating__choose" id="gender">
                    <div class="calculating__choose-item calculating__choose-item_active">Женщина</div>
                    <div class="calculating__choose-item">Мужчина</div>
                </div>

                <div class="calculating__subtitle">
                    Ваша конституция
                </div>
                <div class="calculating__choose calculating__choose_medium">
                    <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Введите рост" class="calculating__choose-item">
                    <input type="text" id="weight" placeholder="Введите вес" class="calculating__choose-item">
                    <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Введите возраст" class="calculating__choose-item">
                </div>

                <div class="calculating__subtitle">
                    Выберите вашу физическая активность
                </div>
                <div class="calculating__choose calculating__choose_big">
                    <div id="low" class="calculating__choose-item">Низкая активность </div>
                    <div id="small" class="calculating__choose-item calculating__choose-item_active">Невысокая
                        активность</div>
                    <div id="medium" class="calculating__choose-item">Умеренная активность</div>
                    <div id="high" class="calculating__choose-item">Высокая активность</div>
                </div>

                <div class="calculating__divider"></div>

                <div class="calculating__total">
                    <div class="calculating__subtitle">
                        Ваша суточная норма калорий:
                    </div>
                    <div class="calculating__result">
                        <span>2700</span> ккал
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>

    <div class="menu">
        <h2 class="title">Наше меню на день</h2>

        <div class="menu__field">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="menu__item">
                    <img src="img/tabs/vegy.jpg" alt="vegy">
                    <h3 class="menu__item-subtitle">Меню "Фитнес"</h3>
                    <div class="menu__item-descr">Меню "Фитнес" - это новый подход к приготовлению блюд: больше свежих
                        овощей и фруктов. Продукт активных и здоровых людей. Это абсолютно новый продукт с оптимальной
                        ценой и высоким качеством!</div>
                    <div class="menu__item-divider"></div>
                    <div class="menu__item-price">
                        <div class="menu__item-cost">Цена:</div>
                        <div class="menu__item-total"><span>229</span> грн/день</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item">
                    <img src="img/tabs/elite.jpg" alt="elite">
                    <h3 class="menu__item-subtitle">Меню “Премиум”</h3>
                    <div class="menu__item-descr">В меню “Премиум” мы используем не только красивый дизайн упаковки, но
                        и качественное исполнение блюд. Красная рыба, морепродукты, фрукты - ресторанное меню без похода
                        в ресторан!</div>
                    <div class="menu__item-divider"></div>
                    <div class="menu__item-price">
                        <div class="menu__item-cost">Цена:</div>
                        <div class="menu__item-total"><span>550</span> грн/день</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item">
                    <img src="img/tabs/post.jpg" alt="post">
                    <h3 class="menu__item-subtitle">Меню "Постное"</h3>
                    <div class="menu__item-descr">Меню “Постное” - это тщательный подбор ингредиентов: полное отсутствие
                        продуктов животного происхождения, молоко из миндаля, овса, кокоса или гречки, правильное
                        количество белков за счет тофу и импортных вегетарианских стейков. </div>
                    <div class="menu__item-divider"></div>
                    <div class="menu__item-price">
                        <div class="menu__item-cost">Цена:</div>
                        <div class="menu__item-total"><span>430</span> грн/день</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="order">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Заказывай пробный день прямо сейчас!</div>
            <form action="#" class="order__form">
                <input required placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" type="text" class="order__input">
                <input required placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="phone" type="phone" class="order__input">
                <img src="icons/right.svg" alt="right">
                <button class="btn btn_dark btn_min">Перезвонить мне</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>

    <div class="promotion">
        <div class="bgc_y"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="promotion__text">
                <div class="title">Акция для новых клиентов!</div>
                <div class="promotion__descr">
                    Мы ценим каждого клиента и предлагаем вам стать одним из них на очень выгодных условиях.
                    Каждому, кто закажет доставку питание на неделю, будет предоставлена скидка в размере
                    <span>20%!</span>
                    <br><br>
                    Акция закончится 20 мая в 00:00
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="promotion__timer">
                <div class="title">Осталось до конца акции:</div>
                <div class="timer">
                    <div class="timer__block">
                        <span id="days">12</span>
                        дней
                    </div>
                    <div class="timer__block">
                        <span id="hours">20</span>
                        часов
                    </div>
                    <div class="timer__block">
                        <span id="minutes">56</span>
                        минут
                    </div>
                    <div class="timer__block">
                        <span id="seconds">20</span>
                        секунд
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="social">
                <div class="subtitle">Мы в социальных сетях:</div>
                <a href="#" class="link">instagram</a>
                <a href="#" class="link">facebook</a>
            </div>
            <div class="pepper">
                <img src="icons/veg.svg" alt="pepper">
            </div>
            <div class="call">
                <div class="subtitle">Или позвоните нам</div>
                <a href="#" class="link">+380678341034</a>
                <a href="#" class="link">+380500941356</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal__dialog">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="modal__close" data-close>&times;</div>
                    <div class="modal__title">Мы свяжемся с вами как можно быстрее!</div>
                    <input required placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" type="text" class="modal__input">
                    <input required placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="phone" type="phone" class="modal__input">
                    <button class="btn btn_dark btn_min">Перезвонить мне</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Не обращайте внимания на не найденные картинки
Кнопка называется 'Связаться с нами'

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: modalTrigger.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: А как написать тогда?

Comment: Там же анонимная функция

Comment: у вас же `querySelectorAll` - это коллекция - надо перебрать - `forEach` или `for()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чем отличаются эти две строчки?

```
modalTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal]'),
...
modalCloseBtn = document.querySelector('[data-close]');
```

> А как написать тогда?

```
modalTrigger = document.querySelector('[data-modal]'),
```

Comment: Data-modal это кнопка на которую нажимают а data-close это крести в углу всплывающего окна

Comment: @Александр Это ответ не на мой вопрос. Чем отличаются эти две строчки?